# what is the smallest addressable memory unit?

Tags: variables, memory

i have came across some people who say that byte is the smallest addressable unit and others say that a memory word is the smallest addressable unit.
But in either case if we use a variable of boolean type, does that mean that other 7 bits(in case of byte) or even more bits(in case of word) will just be let unused?

Comment: Boolean are often implemented as a special case of an `int` and yes the "space" is wasted.  Unless you want to store several "variables" in a bit masked int.

Answer (score 1):

In ye olde days, there were computers with 36-bit words (for example). Those words were the smallest addressable units even though they could hold four-bytes (plus) of data.

If happen to be working on such a processor, words are the smallest addressable unit.

In nearly all case these days a WORD will be the same as a byte. (Although some assembly languages use WORD to indicate two-bytes).

Comment: okay, but i want to know that what about the remaining word when we use something like a bit-field value which is not a multiple of 8bits(ex. 3 bits) , in a c program.

Comment: Is this a constraint set by the hardware engineers? Does this mean that on SSDs and HDDs in the same system the minimum block size can be only 1 byte instead of 1 bit?

Comment: So, if I build a machine which uniquely addresses group of 9bits, then in that technically a `WORD` is 9 bits but a `BYTE` is still 8 bits, right?